# How can I validate an email address in Python

Tags: python

```
email = input("Put your mail: ") 

def check(email):

    if not "@" in email:
        print("İnvalid email") 
        print()
    elif " " in email:
        print("İnvalid email") 


    elif not email[-4:] in ".com.org.edu.gov.net":
        if email[-7:] in ".com.tr.org.tr.edu.tr.gov.tr.net.tr": 
            print("Valid mail")
            print()

        else:   
            print("İnvalid email")
            print()

    else:
        print("Valid mail")

check(email)
```

When user writes example : "@gmail.com " it says "valid mail" .
Even though there is nothing written before the @ sign, it says valid. What should I add to this code to fix this error?

Comment: Validating email addresses is [notoriously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript) [difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression). However, to answer your specific question, you should validate that the email does not start with the "@" sign.

Comment: Generally one would use some regex matching to perform this work. Is this homework? If so, you could look to see if the first character is `@`, as an option.

Comment: First, ensure there's only one "!@". Look at everything before the "@" and validate. Then validate the TLD (.com, .org, etc). Right now, "@m.or" will also be valid

Comment: There's a [geeksforgeeks article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-email-address-valid-or-not-in-python/) about this.

Answer (score 1):

I've refactored your code a little , so it is a bit easier to read (and included the username check):

```
email = input("Put your mail: ")

SupportedProviders = ["gmail", "yahoo", "hotmail"]
SupportedTDL = ["com", "org", "edu", "gov", "net", "tr"]
Separators = ['@', '.']    

def ValidateEmail(_email):
    if "@" not in _email or " " in _email:
        return "Invalid email"
    
    for sep in Separators:
        _email = _email.replace(sep, '|')
    _username, _provider, _tdl = _email.split("|", 3)

    if len(_username) < 1:
        return "Invalid email"
    elif _provider not in SupportedProviders:
        return "Invalid email"
    elif _tdl not in SupportedTDL:
        return "Invalid email"

    return "Valid email"


print(ValidateEmail(email))
```

Now, lets go through the changes.

I've added 2 lists (`SupportedProvieds` and `SupportedTDL`), which contain all available email providers and top-level domains
And another list that contain all the separators that could be in the email.

(I also renamed your `check` method to `ValidateEmail` so it is more apparent what it does.)

In `ValidateEmail` I firstly loop through the `Separators` list and replace them with "|" symbol (it will normalize the separators, so we can split email address into username,email provider and TDL later.)

*Note that I've used "|", because an email address can't contain such symbol.

Also it is useful to know the basic email address structure, it goes as follows: `"username@emailProvider.TDL"`

Lastly I check if the length of the username is valid (I don't know its real minimum length, so I just used 1) and if provider/tdl are in respected allowed lists.

Let me know if you have any further questions!

Answer (score -2):

In general, you want to avoid hand-rolling parsing solutions as it is very difficult.  I would suggest: [email.utils.parser](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/email.utils.html#email.utils.parseaddr)